# Mysql sub query with multiple rows returned

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am trying to get the zip codes that are within a certain latitude and longitude and then using the zip codes returned pull all posts within the given area. The numbers for latitude and longitude are variables but for testing purposes they are hard numbers.
Can someone guide me in the right direction to make this work?

Query #1 - works selects post

```
SELECT user_id, session, zip, price, city, state, post_id, category, shortDesc,  fpi 
FROM post ORDER BY post.post_id DESC;
```

Query #2 - works selects zip codes in area

```
SELECT count(value) as duplicate, value 
from (SELECT DISTINCT zipcode as value from zip 
  WHERE latitude BETWEEN 27.747 AND 28.147 
  UNION all 
   SELECT DISTINCT zipcode FROM zip 
   WHERE longitude BETWEEN -82.657 AND -82.257) 
as tbl group by value having count(value) > 1;
```

Query as subquery

Tried: Failed

```
SELECT user_id, session, zip, price, city, state, post_id, category, shortDesc,  fpi 
FROM post 
WHERE zip = (
  SELECT count(value) as duplicate ,value 
  from (SELECT DISTINCT zipcode as value from zip 
    WHERE latitude BETWEEN 27.747 AND 28.147 
    UNION all SELECT DISTINCT zipcode FROM zip 
     WHERE longitude BETWEEN -82.657 AND -82.257) 
  as tbl group by value having count(value) > 1) 
ORDER BY post.post_id DESC;
```

error #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Next Try: FAILED

```
SELECT user_id, session, zip, price, city, state, post_id, category, shortDesc,  fpi 
FROM post WHERE zip = (select distinct zipcode from zip 
  where latitude between 27.747 AND 28.147) 
  IN ( select distinct zipcode from zip 
    where longitude between -82.657 AND -82.257);
```

1242 - Sub query returns more than 1 row

Next Try: FAILED

```
SELECT user_id, session, zip, price, city, state, post_id, category, shortDesc,  fpi 
FROM post 
WHERE zip = ANY (
  select distinct zipcode from zip 
  where latitude between 27.747 AND 28.147) 
IN ( select distinct zipcode from zip 
     where longitude between -82.657 AND -82.257);
```

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want

try this

```
select user_id, session, zip, price, city, state, post_id, category, shortDesc,  fpi 
FROM post WHERE zip in
(SELECT DISTINCT zipcode from zip where 
(latitude BETWEEN 27.747 AND 28.147) AND (longitude BETWEEN -82.657 AND -82.257))
```

Comment: This appears to work on the data set that I have. I just have a hard time wrapping my head around DISTINCT and why you don't have to specify it on both sides of the AND so that you get values that appear in both data sets. Very good answer for not understanding the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should work.:

```
SELECT user_id, session, zip, price, city, 
  state, post_id, category, shortDesc, fpi 
FROM post WHERE zip in (SELECT DISTINCT zipcode as value 
                                      from zip 
                                    WHERE latitude BETWEEN 27.747 AND 28.147 
                                    and longitude BETWEEN -82.657 AND -82.257)
   ORDER BY post.post_id DESC;
```